# How do I import a C# monobehavior script during runtime and add it to a component?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, streamwriter, gameobject, runtime-compilation

I am a bit of a newbie in Unity3D and I have made a script that generates a new C# script (on void Start() for now). this C# script has to be added to a gameObject after it has been made. I tried to find a way how to import this script during runtime, but I am totally lost.

The following scripts are attached to the same gameObject and the generated script has to be added as a component to that same gameObject as well.

This generates the script:

```
    public class mutator : MonoBehaviour {

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    string directoryName = @"C://blabla/bla";
    string directoryPathString = Path.Combine(directoryName, gameObject.name);
    string fileName = gameObject.name + ".cs";
    string filePathString = Path.Combine(directoryPathString, fileName);

    if(!Directory.Exists(directoryPathString))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryPathString);
    if(!File.Exists(filePathString)) {
        using(FileStream fs = File.Create(filePathString)) {
            using (StreamWriter s = new StreamWriter(fs)) {
                s.WriteLine("using UnityEngine;");
                s.WriteLine("using System.Collections;");
                s.WriteLine("public class " + gameObject.name + " : MonoBehaviour {");
                s.WriteLine("   public int organelles = 0;");
                s.WriteLine("   void Start () {");
                s.WriteLine("       foreach(Transform T in transform){");
                s.WriteLine("           organelles = organelles + 1;");
                s.WriteLine("       }");
                s.WriteLine("   }");
                s.WriteLine("}");

            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

This tries to find the script and add it to the gameObject:

```
    public class DNA_translator : MonoBehaviour {

public string fileName;
public string url;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    string directoryName = @"C://blabla/bla";
    string directoryPathString = directoryName + "/" + gameObject.name;
    fileName = gameObject.name + ".cs";
    string filePathString = directoryPathString + "/" + fileName;


    if(File.Exists(filePathString)) {
        print("file exists");
        url = "file:///" + filePathString;
        print(url);
        UnityEngineInternal.APIUpdaterRuntimeServices.AddComponent(gameObject, "Assets/Scripts/DNA/DNA_translator.cs (21,4)", gameObject.name);


    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}
}
```

The script works if the last script is turned off during the first run of the program and turned on the second time the program runs (of course because Unity had the time to compile the script).

Any help is very much appreciated!

A

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the method in the DNA_translator class from Start to something else, and call it once the file has been generated.

Comment: That's very smart. Still every first time I run and the script is (I guess) not yet imported to the Unity Asset Library (or however it may be called) I get an error:  Component Type 'Organism' not found.

I guess I must use some kind of asset importer before I can run the script. Do you know more about that?

Comment: Is it necessary to compile during runtime? Can it be replaced with a prewritten class? It seems that the only variable in the generated script is the class name which has no impact on the function of the class. Try just pre compiling the class with a general name and attach it to the gameObject.

Comment: Also it does not actually add the script as a component anymore if I call the method (which I now changed to "translate()") from the "mutator" script.

Comment: Yes it is absolutely necessary to compile during runtime because after a while lots of gameObjects will be created which have a mutator and a translator. The translator adds the script to the component and the mutator makes a small change to the script for every new gameObject that is made. Therefore I do not yet know how the script will look like before I run the program.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the wrong path, but it's a good thing you actually tried something before posting. Respect for that.

This is actually much simplier than you think, write two seperate scripts (components), in the first scipt do this:

```
void Start(){

     NameOfSecondClass referenceToNewComponent= gameObject.AddComponent<NameOfSecondClass>();

}
```

This will add new component to the gameObject the first script is on, all variable values will be default. Defaults are empty string, zeroes, false bools, etc...

To declare defaults just declare variables like this

```
public int varName = 5;
```

Same goes for different types.

If you want to add component and set new values dynamically from the script that you are adding new component from do this after adding component in the first code I wrote here in void Start().

```
referenceToNewComponent.varName = something.
```

Of course variable whose values you are changing needs to be public.

I wrote all of this on mobile, so there are maybe typos in here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Neven Ignjic,

Comment: Also forgot to say, you can avoid having to compile during runtime, there is always a simple way to do it, you just gotta find it. If no, tag gameObject and add different script to them based on tag.

Comment: I understand that I can also make a class like that. I can see why you come up with your answer because I have not stated my problem that clearly yet.

I have a mutator script and a translator script. The mutator script for now just writes pre defined lines in a new file. Later on the mutator script will - if the file does not yet exist - write a code which I defined for a lot of operators that exist in csharp. if the file exists it will on a certain interval create random changes to the code that I defined.

Comment: The translator will later try to remove all the lines that cause errors and add what is left to the gameObject. For now I just want to see if it is possible to add a script that is made during runtime to the gameObject that needs it.

Comment: Well that's another thing, never did that because I always managed to find some easy workaround, in your case that is too hard because of so many changes.